# How to stop vscode from auto removing double quote?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatter

So I want to write this code

```
db.students.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "nmae": "name" } } )
```

But every time I save it always becomes like this

```
db.students.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { nmae: "name" } } )
```

The quotes are always removed for the key. How to stop it? I use prettier. Is it the prettier causing this?

Comment: because they are not needed for the key

Comment: So the unqouted key will still work?

Comment: Yes. Everything is fine. It won’t remove it if you have a key of, say `”this-needs quotes”`

Comment: What language is this?? (I'd say JS, in which case rioV8 and Sami are right; but could be something else)

Comment: have you tried the unquoted version?